# How can I change my DB schema while running a spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, migration, mixins

I want to test a model mixin, so I want to create a fake activerecord model to include it in, and then test the behavior of that model.

The specs I have from another context require the db table of the fake model to exist (I know, I shouldn't depend on this, but that's how they are for now). So I need to create a table for the fake model (`TestModel`) while the spec is running.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, treat the faked model as you would an external service and mock out the other model's container. Something like

```
faked_model = mock "FakeModelThatShouldntExist"
faked_model.stub!(:name).and_return("jwo")
FakeModelThatShouldntExist.should_receive(:find_by_customer_id).and_returns(faked_model)
```

Run tests as normal

Answer (score 0):

This might seem like overkill,
but in my view, if a library needs to be tested in abstraction
it may be worth pulling it out into a gem or plugin.

Generally in my app I test the consequence of mixins, rather than the mixins themselves.
And keep the mixin tests inside the relevant plugin or gem.

If the contains important business logic (or your company won't let you open source it) keep it as a plugin.

If its generally usable, then break it out as a gem.

Here's an example of a gem I abstracted
http://bit.ly/hJ4QC2

Pretty much just use the `rails g plugin` template and add something like the following

```
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => "sqlite3",
  :database => ":memory:"
)

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 0) do
  create_table :somethings, :force => true do |t|
    t.string :size
  end
end
```

and you should have yourself a plugin test